# "Plug an Ethernet cable into this computer"? With no connections are available

Tags: internet

I restarted my Windows 7 laptop 2 times and nothing happened. I have no internet at all. I chose to troubleshoot it and it told me "Plug an Ethernet cable into this computer" I have no idea what that means... It says something like "A. Ethernet cable looks like a telephone cable but with larger connections on the ends. Plug this cable into the opening on the back or side of the computer. Make sure the other end of the cable is plugged into the router. If that does not help, try using a different cable." Can someone explain to me what to do exactly in a less complex way? I'm not a computer genius so I don't really know what to do. It also said "No connections are available" even though all the phones and iPads in the house are working perfectly fine. There is also an update for Windows 10 but I did not update it yet.

Comment: I don't know if it can get less complex than that...  Possibly call someone to help you locally.

Comment: It sounds like your wireless is disabled or not working correctly, so it's defaulted back to other available network connections, in this case an ethernet connection. What model laptop is it? It may be as simple as hitting a button to re-enable wireless.

Answer (score 2):

These are some suggestions for restoring your wireless connection in Windows 7.

1. If you are using a router, push the reset button on the router to toggle it off, then wait 10 seconds and push the reset button on the router again to toggle it back on.
2. Try uninstalling the wireless driver and reinstalling the driver and reboot your computer.
3. [Use the  built-in Windows System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833).

---

Ethernet is a family of computer networking technologies for local area (LAN) and larger networks. An ethernet cable looks like a telephone cable, but the connector is wider. A telephone cable has 4 pins, but an ethernet cable has 8.

If your laptop has an ethernet port, then plug in an ethernet cable to make a wired connection from your modem or router to your laptop. The ethernet cable connector will make a soft clicking noise when the plastic spring engages in the ethernet port, indicating that the ethernet cable is firmly plugged in to the ethernet socket as it should be to have a proper electrical connection.

Ethernet cables come in different colors and lengths. These two pictures show what an ethernet cable looks like.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could be wrong:

1. Your computer has an issue with the connection. You can see your adapters by search for Network Adapters in the Windows search box. At least one Ethernet adapter should show as enabled.
2. You were running on WiFi and accidentally turned it off. See if you have WiFi on the machine  and can turn it back on.
3. The Cable has an issue. Are both ends plugged in? Is it damaged in anyway? You should green lights on the places where the cable plugs in.
4. The router and or modems (the boxes where the internet comes in form the road and goes to your machines may have an issue.) A simple unplug, wait 20 seconds and re plug can help this situation.